# Website compatibility with CSS3 and HTML5

Tags: html, css, compatibility

How can I test a website against CSS3 and HTML5 compatibility in a browser?
I think about something like http://css3test.com/ for a selected website. Maybe with a javascript injection to check the website compatibility against browsers.

Comment: Every website is compatible with HTML5 and CSS3. Just not every website uses it.
A browser isn't always compatible with HTML5 and CSS3

Comment: The question is not about the website. It is about the range of different browser. Not every browser is compatible to all CSS3 features, as you can see on http://css3test.com/ or http://caniuse.com . I want to test which browser is compatible to the selected website. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Ohh, now I get it. I don't really think there exists a tool you can do this with, but it would be possible to make your own. You can parse the HTML & CSS and check for all the HTML5/CSS3 stuff. If anything isn't suppurted in a major browser, and there isn't existing something that works either (like -webkit-something) then the browser wouldn't be compatible

Comment: Oh, "(…) compatibility in *that* browser/in each different browser" I didn't get it without your comment.

Comment: For CSS: you could extract the existing CSS with a node/grunt/gulp/etc tool, pass it to [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) and see if there's any difference before/after (maybe Autoprefixer doesn't check if a prefixed property is already there and output a new one so you now have twice the same. Then just clean both CSS and compare the result I guess)

Answer (score 0):

For while your programming this link is pretty useful providing you with all the tags and compability per browser: http://caniuse.com/

This is a tool to check all browser (although its pretty slow), i suppose there are others just google for "browser website test: http://browsershots.org/

Hope this helps you